# Cron Jobs - Doesn't seem to execute

Tags: php, apache, ssh, cron

Looking through the internet at examples on how to run a php script from a cron job I've settled on this command:

```
php -q /home/myuseraccount/public_html/crontest/crontest.php
```

I tried running this from SSH and had success! But when I try this as a cron job nothing happens. I have it set to run every minute. Nothing happens. It should create a text file with the current time in it:

```
<?php
$file = '/home/myuseraccount/public_html/crontest/test.txt';
$now = time();

file_put_contents($file, $now, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

?>
```

It should also email me. It doesn't. I'm assuming it would email me no matter what, like if there was a failure?

It's not possible cron jobs are somehow disabled is it? - I'd assume I wouldnt even be able to set them up...

Is there any way, like from SSH, to test cron jobs?

I've never successfully been able to get cron jobs to work, so I don't know if it's a server issue or just ignorance.

--EDIT--

My cron log file seems to just show a bunch of LIST's and REPLACE's

Comment: Can we please get a full view of your crontab file?

Comment: i assume you mean this: ***** php -q /home/fss/public_html/crontest/crontest.php

Comment: If you want to verify that cron works, create a job that just does `echo foo` and see if you get email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `crond` wasn't running....

```
#service crond restart
Stopping crond: cannot stop crond: crond is not running.   [FAILED]
Starting crond:                                            [  OK  ]
```

Works now.

Answer (score 0):

Consider checking your logs for cron at /var/log/syslog

Please also make sure you can actually write to the file/directory (chmod permissions). Even further ensure that the crontab userlevel can write to the file/directory as well.

I just tried your file and it does execute fine for me, will attempt to do it as a crontab int he same way as you.

EDIT: Ran it as a cronjob and that worked as well, not sure what the issue is!

Comment: This should indeed be a comment.

Comment: Excuse my lack of Stackoverflow knowledge :)

Comment: ***** php -q /home/fss/public_html/crontest/crontest.php

Comment: You might want to delete/edit your answer before someone downvotes it.

Comment: Added some actually comments/suggestions.

Comment: I'm able to run the file in a browser and it creates the text file, so chmod should be fine?

Comment: Out of curiosity what is the -q flag for? I don't have it on my install. I just ran your script via my crontab and it worked fine.

Comment: I don't know. everyone uses it in their examples. I think it suppresses headers?

Comment: Ah ok, I wish I could help further but I'm not sure what else to do as it's working on my setup.